# Public hosting of XML Schemas

Tags: xsd

Does anyone know of a free service that provides public hosting of XML schemas? I just want to be able to upload an XSD file so they can be publicly accessed to validate against and be reasonably confident that the URL will be available for the long term.

Seems like a natural given the intention of schemas, but I can't find anything of the sort.

Of course XSD can be hosted on any publicly accessible web server, but I'm really looking for a dedicated service for XSD hosting: for instance, something that would index the XSD, make them searchable, taggable, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An xsd is just a file, so you could use any hosting service, most are free for public and/or "small" (e.g. <2GB) storage:  github, bitbucket, google appengine, heroku, dropbox

Comment: I know, I was just hoping there was a service out there specifically intended for hosting schema. For instance, something that would index them, make them searchable, etc. Generally a common place where people would know to go to look for schema.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm that's an interesting point, you should add it to your question. Something a little bit similar is registries for web-services that *use* XSD, i.e. WSDL and UDDI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Discovery Though it's not quite what you want; and I don't think it's really taken off anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I edited my question to include more details on what I'm looking for.